# Is PQntuples guaranteed to be 1 with PQsetSingleRowMode?

Tags: postgresql, libpq

I've started using `PQsetSingleRowMode` to be able to have more control over the data as it is streaming after `PQsendQueryParams`. You need to call `PQgetResult` a lot more, but is it as a matter of fact guaranteed that you'll get a single record each time, and thus `PQntuples` returns 1?

I'm asking because I'm not sure if it's 100% safe to drop the code that checks for `PQntuples` and loops that many times. Also I would not mind if it were greater than 1. Or if there were a separate “fire hose mode” where you get *any* records that have been fully transferred over the network since the previous `PQgetresult`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In single row mode `PQgetResult` will always produce a result with at most one row. Be aware that the last `PGresult *` returned will be empty.

If you want the result set in chunks of more than a single row, you'd have to use cursors and `FETCH`.

Comment: It's not that I _want_ my result sets be of a certain number, I would like to get _any_ records that have been transmitted since the last call rightaway. But I guess `PQgetResult` of the next row will return immediately if it's transmitted already, so I'm pleased you confirm I don't need to loop over `PGntuples` with `PQsetSingleRowMode` as it's going to be either 1 or 0.